# How can I make all the verbiage on a Listbox row available?

Tags: c#, listbox, compact-framework, horizontal-scrolling, .net-1.1

Using .NET 1.1, Compact Framework version, neither `Listbox` nor `Listbox.Items` has a horizontal scrollbar, Wordwrap, or Tooltip property.

So if the text I add to a Listbox is longer than the Listbox's width, how can I make it visible/accessible to the user?

Answer (score 1):

To make the horizontal scroll bar always visible, just set it's property to true.

```
// Display a horizontal scroll bar.
   listBoxName.HorizontalScrollbar = true;
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.horizontalscrollbar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Perhaps you missed the part about this being Compact Framework 1.1?

Comment: Yes; I have no HorizontalScrollbar available.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not seem to find any information specific to CE 1.1.  Maybe it is possible to create a custom list box object?  Just out of curiosity, may I ask why you must use 1.1?

Comment: @Kirkland: Because the powers-that-be here still wear pocket protectors and polyester britches. Believe me, if I had a choice in the matter, we would have abandoned this archaic technology long ago.